# write to sqlite db packaged inside a jar

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite

I'm trying to use a DB for reading and writing that  is contained in a JAR. 
I can read in it, but can't write throwed exeception :

`java.sql.SQLException: path to '/database/scddata.db': 'LocationOfJar/database' does not exist`

Is there any way I can bundle the database file inside a JAR?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will you read only on this db or write also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jar files does not allows to write.

So :

1. define a working path (in properties for example). Let's call it : `workingPath/file.db.`
2. on init of your program, before opening your db.

   - check if db exists in working path
   - if does not exists : copy your jar file.db file to `workingPath/file.db` .
3. Then you program will use the db from `workingPath/file.db` for execution.